# How to multiply two values in an object

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins

I have this table in JSON data:

[image]

I want to do: `Res [i] = Code[i] * Code_V[i];`

My script is :

```
get_full_Res  = function(obj)  {
  $.each(obj, function() {
    $.each(this, function(k, v) {
      console.log("k : "+k+" v: "+v)
    });
  });
}
```

I don't know how to use jQuery after doing a loop through JSON data. Please help

Comment: could you post html for this?

Comment: or even better, can you post the JSON data, not the image of it already rendered

Comment: i'm sorry. it's wrong. i will edit my post

Comment: I was using JSON transformation for excel file

Comment: Ok, but can't you show us the JSON data, so we can see how it is formatted and then help you on how to iterate and get the values?

Answer (score 0):

```
Your object is like 
var obj = [{
    "Name": "X0012",
    "Ps": "PO10",
    "Code": 31,
    "Code_V": 10,
    "Res": 0
}, {
    "Name": "X0013",
    "Ps": "PO11",
    "Code": 22,
    "Code_V": 11,
    "Res": 0
}, {
    "Name": "X0014",
    "Ps": "PO12",
    "Code": 1,
    "Code_V": 12,
    "Res": 0
}];
then we can use for loop here

for(var k in obj)
{
  console.log(obj[k].Code * obj[k].Code_V);
}
```